# LDAP Authentication and Android

Tags: android, ldap

I'm trying to authenticate with a tomcat server through LDAP. Then after I'm authenticated send a basic GET request to get some data back (XML), and display it to the user. How would I go about authenticating with the server and then performing this request? Are there any good good guides or libraries for this? I'm pretty new with this protocol..

Comment: I don't quite get who does the authentication in your scenario: the app on the phone or the Tomcat server that the app is talking to. Maybe you could clarify that?

Generally, using LDAP from Java means using JNDI, i.e. the packages javax.naming and subpackages. Those have been part of Java SE since way back (1.3?). However, the Android SDK does not provide those packages. You might have to use HTTP Auth with the Tomcat server which then talks to the LDAP directory.

Comment: Server does the authentication. Client sends an initial user/pass pair which the server authenticates (for LDAP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an example of client authentication at [HttpClient Examples](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/branches/4.0.x/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientAuthentication.java).